# How to find ID(row) attached to image from database and then call it in a SQL query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a image/text upload form that uploads and displays them onto the page.
There are the rows: image, text, and id.

The first image uploaded is 1, the second is 2, and so forth.

Everytime an image is displayed, it's own delete button is also echo'ed.

Whenever the delete button is clicked, it's action is: delete.php.

I need to know how to fetch the ID of the image in which the delete button was clicked on, here is my code:

delete.php :

```
<?php
// connect to db
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "boxofmem_GMSConnect");

$sql = "DELETE FROM images WHERE id= ID OF IMAGE GOES HERE";

mysqli_query($db, $sql); //deletes it

header('Location: teachers.php');
?>
```

teachers.php (where the delete button is echoed with the image from the database)

```
<?php 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "boxofmem_GMSConnect");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div id='img_div'>";
    echo "<p style='font-family:Roboto;color:white;font-size:20px;'>".$row['text']."</p>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='deletepost.php'>
        <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete Post'/>
        </form>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' ' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>";
    echo "</div>";
}


?>
```

SO yeah, in short, I am having trouble fetching the ID of specific images in the database according to which delete button the user clicked..
All help is appreciated! This is my attempt so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You need one hidden variable which'll store id of that image & need to access that in your `delete.php` file

```
 //Delete.php  
 <?php
    // connect to db
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "boxofmem_GMSConnect");
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM images WHERE id= $id OF IMAGE GOES HERE";

    mysqli_query($db, $sql); //deletes it

    header('Location: teachers.php');
    ?>

//teachers.php
<?php 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "boxofmem_GMSConnect");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>


<div id='img_div'>
    <p style='font-family:Roboto;color:white;font-size:20px;'><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>;
    <form method='post' action='deletepost.php'>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete Post'>
    </form>
    <img src='images/<?php $row['image']; ?>' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
</div>
<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: You are a god sir, thank you so much! Worked like a charm.